# How to make Nutch crawler to crawl only specific URLS?

Tags: nutch

I'm aware that regex can be used to restrict the pages that will be downloaded. But, I would like to crawl only those pages where the anchor link in a given page is in a set of urls. For example, i have an array with words like ['computer','software','hardware','operating system','thread'], I would only like to crawl those urls whose anchor text contains one of these words in the array. Where should I implement this kind of logic in Nutch? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, the URLFilters aren't much use as they deal with the URL string only. You could achieve what you described by implementing a custom HTMLParseFilter in which you'd access the [ParseData](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/nutch/parse/ParseData.java) for the current document. It contains the Outlinks which you could filter based on their anchor value.

There are loads of examples online on how to write a plugin and/or custom HTMLParseFilter, see for instance [MetaTagsParser](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/trunk/src/plugin/parse-metatags/src/java/org/apache/nutch/parse/metatags/MetaTagsParser.java).